# plotchar only if signal cross a midline in TSI indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'd like to plotchar or barcolor only when the signal line corss the midline in TSI indicator. I tried with crossover but without lucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSI indicator from built-in library. Added a `barcolor` function with a conditional. Used `cross` function, so it will highlight the cross in any direction. If you want to specify - use `crossunder` or `crossover`

```
//@version=4
study("True Strength Indicator", shorttitle="TSI", format=format.price, precision=4, resolution="")
long = input(title="Long Length", type=input.integer, defval=25)
short = input(title="Short Length", type=input.integer, defval=13)
signal = input(title="Signal Length", type=input.integer, defval=13)
price = close
double_smooth(src, long, short) =>
    fist_smooth = ema(src, long)
    ema(fist_smooth, short)
pc = change(price)
double_smoothed_pc = double_smooth(pc, long, short)
double_smoothed_abs_pc = double_smooth(abs(pc), long, short)
tsi_value = 100 * (double_smoothed_pc / double_smoothed_abs_pc)
tsi_signal = ema(tsi_value, signal)


tsi_cross = crossover(tsi_value, 0)
barcolor(timeframe.period == '240' and tsi_cross ? color.yellow : na)

plot(tsi_value, color=#3BB3E4)
plot(tsi_signal, color=#FF006E)
hline(0, title="Zero")
```

Comment: can you specify what is not equal? If the tsi_signal was on the one side of the zero line and next bar on the other side of the zero line - it will highlight that bar.

Comment: sorry, my fault! :) 
I'd like to color even only in 4h timeframe:
`barcolor(timeframe.period == '4h' ? (crossover(tsi_value, 0) ? color.yellow : na) :na)` but I dont' understand why isn't yellow.

Comment: The cross function should be initialized in the global scope. `tsi_cross = crossover(tsi_value, 0), barcolor(timeframe.period == '4h' ? tsi_cross ? color.yellow : na)`

Comment: `tsi_cross = crossover(tsi_value, 0)
barcolor(timeframe.period == '4h' ? tsi_cross ? color.yellow : na :na)`

without the second na I get an error, with second na I don't have yellow bar

Comment: ah, sorry about that, could use only one ternary with `and` operator `tsi_cross = crossover(tsi_value, 0), barcolor(timeframe.period == '4h' and tsi_cross ? color.yellow : na)`

Comment: changed '4h' to '240'. ps: Updated the answer with code.